# NullPointerException @Autowired on Service. JAX-RS + SpringBoot + WildFly

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, jax-rs, autowired

Hello I'm new to SpringBoot and i don't know how to solve this problem. I'm using an ApacheDS server and I'm building a Rest Controller and uscing Spring Security. I have this issue since last week and I need to solve it. When I try to get a simple return from my @Autowired Service it's always Null.
Here's my configClass. That's not the problem...it all works fine. Till I get to my controller with this path "http://127.0.0.1:9080/RestServices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/git/rest/autowired/2". Everything works fine but i got a null pointer exception when I try to use a single method of my autowired service. I'mDeplying on WildFly 14

```
@Configuration @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "eu.a2a.ent.restservice.service","eu.a2a.ent.restservice.testautowired"})public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;  
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{ 
        
        logger.debug("Starting authentication {}",auth.ldapAuthentication().hashCode());
        
        auth            
        .ldapAuthentication() /
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people,dc=example,dc=com")         
        .contextSource() 
        .url("ldap://localhost:10389/")
        .and()
        .passwordCompare() 
        .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())      
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");             
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        
        http.csrf().disable();
          http            
          .authorizeRequests() 
          .anyRequest() 
          .fullyAuthenticated() 
          .and()
          .httpBasic()            
          .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        
        logger.info("Sono passato per il run");
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityConfig.class, "--debug");         
    }           
}
```

Here's my rest controller

```
@Path("/rest")public class SampleService {
@Autowired
private IAutowired autowired;

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleService.class);

@GET
@Path("/hello/{name}")
public String hello(@PathParam("name") String name)
{
    return "hi " + name; //this works
}


@GET
@Path("/autowired")
public String autowired()
{
        return autowired.hello();   
}
```

}

Here's my Interface

```
public interface IAutowired {

String hello();
}
```

and my Service

```
@Service
public class AutowiredService implements IAutowired {

@Override
public String saluta() {
    return "Hello, I'm Hello";
}
}
```

Here's my pom.xml if you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<artifactId>RestServices</artifactId>
<groupId>eu.a2a.ent</groupId>
<name>Spring Boot Security Sample</name>
<description>Spring Boot Security Sample</description>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springframework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>       
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>            
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>      
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>        
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>        
</dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>            
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>           
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>           
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>          
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>            
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>        
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>                
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
               <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
          </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>eu/a2a/ent/restservice/secure/SecurityConfig.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>              

    </plugins>
    <finalName>ENT</finalName>
</build>    
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    
    <!-- Repository per Oracle funzionante-->
    <repository>
        <id>oracle_repository</id>
        <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
        
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I've tried using the @EnableSpringConfigured and using @Configurable on my "AutowiredService" too but it seems not working. This is quite a big problem since I always used the @Autowired annotation like that and it worked. I don't get now why many people use this annotation like me and work but it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the package structure for `AuthenticationEntryPoint`?
You need to make sure that beans are defined under either of below packages

1. `eu.a2a.ent.restservice.service`
2. `eu.a2a.ent.restservice.testautowired`

Comment: "eu.a2a.ent.restservice.secure" but that's not the problem...the autowire for AuthenticationEntryPoint works fine. It's the other @Autowired for my "IAutowired" that doesn't work. My SecurityConfig class package is "eu.a2a.ent.restservice" so that he can Scan automatically the other subpackages and components. Seems working for AuthenticationEntryPoint but not for my IAutowired service.

Comment: Can you try with adding annotation  `@Named ` before class `SampleService `?